# Isolating and displaying a specific element within a hash

Tags: ruby

I am currently having trouble writing a test that addresses the `eligibility_settings` of a record I have. I am having trouble pulling out one of the specific elements from this hash.

Specifically I want to test that by making a change elsewhere in a different function that changes the min age of a specific player, and so what I am really trying to test is the `eligibility_settings.min_age`.  But i'm having trouble within my test isolating that out.

My hash looks like this

```
{
                    :name => "player1",
                   :label => "redTeam_1_1",
                   :group => "adult",
                    :teamId => 7,
    :eligibility_settings => {
                          "min_age" => 18,
                    "player_gender" => "female",
              "union_players_only"  => true
    }
}
```

However when I try looping through this hash, I am having trouble isolating that one element.

i've tried something like

```
team.get_players.first.map do |settings, value|
  value.tap do |x, y|
    y[3]
  end
end
```

However It seems like what i've been trying, and my approach has not been working quite right.

Would anyone have any idea what I could do with this?

Comment: huh? Why are you _iterating_? Just fetch the value directly. `hash[:eligibility_settings]['min_age']` (based on what you said your hash looks like)

Comment: omg I feel like I waaay over thought that one, you are absolutely right. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @SergioTulentsev gave the proper response, in the future if you are going to be looping through hashes, below is one way to iterate through the keys and grab the value you want.

```
 hash = {
                :name => "player1",
               :label => "redTeam_1_1",
               :group => "adult",
                :teamId => 7,
  :eligibility_settings => {
                      "min_age" => 18,
                "player_gender" => "female",
          "union_players_only"  => true
   }
}

hash.map do |settings, value|
 p hash[:eligibility_settings]['min_age'] if settings == :eligibility_settings
end # output 18
```